# Clojure: Why does a function's metadata change when I re-enter its definition?

Tags: clojure, metadata

Like so:

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.0
user=> (defn f [x] x)
#'user/f
user=> (meta f)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name f}
user=> (defn f [x] x)
#'user/f
user=> (meta f)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name f, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 1, :arglists ([x])}
user=>
```

Why doesn't the call to `meta` return the same value each time?

UPDATE: by playing some more I was able to get an answer to my immediate question. `defn` macro-expands to a form which adds `(meta (var f)` to `f`'s metadata. And `(meta (var f)` includes the extra info that isn't in `(meta f)` when `f` is defined the first time.  So my question now becomes, why is `defn` implemented like this?

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.0
user=> (defn f [x] x)
#'user/f
user=> (meta f)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name f}
user=> (meta (var f))
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name f, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 1, :arglists ([x])}
user=> (macroexpand '(defn f [x] x))
(def f (.withMeta (clojure.core/fn f ([x] x)) (.meta (var f)))) ; (.meta x) seems to be the same as (meta x)
user=>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this behaviour was more or less "accidental" in Clojure 1.2, and has been changed in 1.3:
http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/964bba0ead8218ee/3ef0c841474c85f4?lnk=gst&q=function+meta+data#3ef0c841474c85f4

In 1.3, only the Var includes the metadata - the function itself isn't assigned any metadata by `defn`.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure uses metadata to store information where the function was read from, docs, etc.  Redefining the function can change that.

---

From http://clojure.org/metadata:

> An important thing to understand about metadata is that it is not considered to be part of the value of an object. As such, metadata does not impact equality (or hash codes). Two objects that differ only in metadata are equal.

Anther way to look at this is to consider the opposite: suppose Clojure did not reset the metadata.

```
(defn fun []
  "docs for the original function"
  ...)
```

and then redefine it:

```
(defn fun []
   ;; no doc string, different body
   ...)
```

Without resetting of the metadata `(doc fun)` would give the "docs for the original function".

Lastly, redefinition of vars is normally done during development and usually not in the normal execution of the program. So it makes sense to wholly redefine it instead of keeping up stuff from previous definitions.

Comment: But I didn't redefine the function, I just entered the same definition a second time (and the place from which the function was read was also the same both times, i.e. the REPL). On the principle that a fixed expression should have a constant value and should avoid side effects wherever possible, it seems odd that something as simple as repeating a `defn` adds new info to the metadata which could just as well have been added the first time (I understand that this doesn't affect the value of the expression, but it still doesn't feel right).

Comment: Defining the function again is redefining, even if the function is the same.  Clojure does not remember your definition, only the compiled code, and it doesn't try to compare the old one with the new one.

Comment: Good points, +1. But I posted the thread from the google group and accepted that as it was closer to what I was looking for.